# Why use different hash personalization for each level of Merkle tree?

Tags: hash, hash-tree

For example zcash uses such approach with Pederesen hash which is collision-resistant, but not preimage-resistant. I assume that it’s used to ensure that we can’t reuse hash from one level which collides with a hash from another.

Comment: Where did you read that the pedersen hash is not preimage resistant? It is hard to find the details in the zcash specifications but it seems plausibly preimage resistant.

Comment: You would need pre-image resistance in order to prove the hiding property of the merkle commitment.

Comment: Multi-dimensional discrete log's hardness should imply it is pre-image resistant.